# How to connect to an IBM DB2 database in AIX from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, db2

We are implementing Manhattan Associates in the company and they provided a IBM AIX box where databases are stored. For the implementation we need to extract some information from the MANH database, but it should happen using SQL Server because we will automate the extraction using SSIS.

The thing is that I cannot connect to the database. I have tried to create a linked server in SQL Server to reach the DB but I believe I don't have the correct provider:

Providers I have installed:

[image: Providers I have installed:]
Could you guys give some recommendations about how to create the connection and how to reach the database?

Many thanks for your support.

Ro A.

Comment: You sure you need to connect to DB2 on AIX?  You don't seem to have a driver for it.  Instead you have drivers for DB2 on IBM i.  Same POWER hardware, completely different OS and DB2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SQL-Server machine needs to have an IBM DB2 Client driver installed (this is different from the existing IBM DB2 for i5/OS driver).  You can download this driver from IBM ([fix central](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27007053))

For best results the version of the DB2 driver should be the same or higher than the version of the DB2-server on AIX. When you install this driver, you can configure it to show a system ODBC database connection for the MANH database, which will then appear in the provider list inside SQL-server with a name like 'IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1' or similar. Then you can created the linked-server.

Comment: As always, thanks a lot for the tips Mao. I'm able to connect to the database. Only as a reference for anyone else who need to connect to this kind of databases, follow this link with full details of the installation of the drivers: http://www.ryslander.com/how-to-install-and-configure-db2-odbc-driver/